# How do I configure spark.driver.memory for connecting from Watson Studio (DSX) notebook to IAE?

Tags: ibm-cloud, analytics-engine, watson-studio

I need to configure `spark.driver.memory` for connecting from a Watson Studio (DSX) notebook to IAE?

Where/how can I configure this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can configure the driver memory from the Ambari, e.g.

```
Ambari UI 
   -> Spark2 
       -> Config
          -> Advanced spark2-env
```

Change the value of `SPARK_DRIVER_MEMORY`